# Interlaced synchronization in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

what is the meaning of Interlaced synchronization in blackberry, why this error is happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interlaced synchronization is when you have two locks being `synchronized` locked in a different order. So, if you have lock `a` and lock `b` and do the following:

```
synchronized(a) {
    // Do stuff ...
    synchronized(b) {
        // Do stuff ...
    }
}
```

And then in another thread:

```
synchronized(b) {
    // Do stuff ...
    synchronized(a) {
        // Do stuff ...
    }
}
```

This would be interlaced synchronization. This situation could result in deadlock, so it should be avoided at all costs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ... and I also found these comments helpful: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/API-5-quot-Interlaced-synchronization-quot/m-p/576228

Comment: Also, see Blackberry [How To detect a deadlock using JDE](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800901/How_To_-_Detect_a_deadlock_using_the_JDE.html?nodeid=1313872&vernum=0)